# Set cookie as HttpOnly from Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie as HttpOnly from within my Silverlight application using the following code:

```
string cookie = String.Format("{0}={1};expires={2};HttpOnly", key, value, expiration.ToString("R"));
HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("cookie", cookie);
```

When I add the "HttpOnly" to the end of the cookie string, the cookie never actually gets set. I'm suspecting that the Silverlight application is considered a script, which would mean that it doesn't have access to HttpOnly cookies.

Is there any other way to get/set cookies in Silverlight such that I would be able to set the HttpOnly attribute?

Comment: You can do the same from the hosted page , may i know whats the reason behind to do the same from SilverlightApplication

Comment: Hey, any news on that question? (I need to achieve the same thing)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I ever did figure out a solution for this as I've since moved away from Silverlight for the project I was trying to do this for. Best of luck though, @coceban.vlad!

Comment: Thank you @Alejo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie never actually get sets because there is no property named HttpOnly exists

Below have listed what property cookie consists of :

```
Property values

1) name=value
2) expires=date
3) domain=domainname
4) path=path
5) secure -> If you set a cookie as secure, the stored cookie information can be accessed only from HTTPS.
```

For detailed explaination on specific properties below is the link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533693(VS.85).aspx

There is no other way to set the cookie in silverlight , only approach is what you are doing is the one